# Class PDO for query

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Goodmorning.
I've an issue with this function inside a class:

```
public function singleField($query,$bindParam,$table){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    while (list($key, $value) = each($bindParam)) {
        $stmt->bindParam($key,$value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        return $row[$table];
    }
}
```

cannot understand what I'm doing wrong, here how I use the class:

```
$conn = new conn;
$conn->singleField("SELECT field FROM table WHERE ID = :ID AND field2 = :field2....etcetc",array(":ID"=>1,":field2"=>"OtherVar...etc..."),"Table");
```

being sure that the connection created in construct is working, now I wonder why the query is not working and not return the result.
I wish I had the opportunity in the array can enter more than one value to pass to BindParam, this is why i created that while but I think that's wrong.
Are three days that I work on.
Thank You for any help.

Comment: You do not need the colon in front of the param name in your params array:  array("ID"=>1,"field2"=>"OtherVar...etc...")

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand exactly, how's the correct way to do it?

Comment: 1) Why would you expect `$row['Table']` to return anything useful? 2) Only the first row will ever be returned (if anything), since you're `return`ing right in the first loop iteration.

Comment: That's $table, and not Table....